# Two different class librarys sharing one static class library

Tags: c#, reflection, scripting

I have a weird thing happening in my code, i have written a bit of software that can run scripts (reflection), every script is a seperate class library. These scripts both include the same class library with some methods and variables (all static vaiables and methods).

but now a weired thing happens it looks like one script is changing values inside the static library class of the other one, and i have no idea how this is possible. can somone explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Yeah... you're gonna need to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...one script is changing the values inside the static library class of the other one

Given this is the same static class, shared across multiple libraries, then the behaviour you describe is correct. When you make something `static` that means that it belongs to a *type* rather than a specific object so changing it means *everything* within the same app domain that references/uses it will see those changes.

Comment: "everything" meaning "everything within the same app domain".

Answer (score 0):

By scripts I assume you mean code running in different threads.

Static classes are not truly static they can be changed, with each thread within the same app domain seeing the same data the static class contains. Therefore a change to a static variable by one thread will be seen by all other threads. Obviously such behaviour is dangerous unless the class is thread safe, therefore you may want to look into implementing some locking in the static class.

Comment: Note that there's the [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx); fields marked with it are not shared between threads.

Comment: @ Dominic Kextel, That did the trick, but i though becouse every script is a difrent assembly they all would have a seperate static library class, and therefore not be able to change the other ones, how is this then?

Comment: @Jeff no that's not the case, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, static does not means its value cannot be changed, instead, a static member have a single instance in memory. This means that if any line of code changes a static member, the change will be visible to everyone else using that member.

Hence the behavior you are facing is perfectly fine.

If you want that the value of a member cannot be changed, use const keyword of C#.

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) MSDN example.

Comment: I know the value can be changed, but i thougth if you include it in difrent assembleys, then each would have their own static variable, but this (thanks to james) i now know is not the case.